# GestureOverlayView on top of a InputMethodService

Tags: android, android-input-method

Is there any way to put a `GestureOverlayView` on top of a keyboard in Android?

If this is not possible, it would be helpful if you can give any references on how to swipe keyboards switch between a touch input method to recognizing the fingermovement while drawing the swipe gesture.

Putting a `GestureOverlayView` on top of a keyboard did not work, the keyboard and gesture recognizer both dont work with this method.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlfow! Please edit your question to include a minimal working example. Paste the code that you tried, otherwise it is not possible to help.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example